# CSS - make a "wall" of divs without blank space between them

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styles

what i am trying to do is to stick divs one to the other to create a wall of them.

The problem is that actually they looks really not sticked one to the other as you can see in my try: http://jsfiddle.net/w3htK/2/

I tryed using `float:left;` but really not helped

I would like the final result to be something like this:

[image]

So that , independently from the content size every div is sticked to the previous without blank parts between them

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If you are looking for a responsive grid then try bootstrap grid http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ or skeleton.js http://www.getskeleton.com/ etc

Comment: @geedubb first im already using a css framework that is not the problem the problem is how to get divs with no blank gutters and sticked one to the other without caring about content length, did you checked my example?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible with CSS alone.  You need a JavaScript package like Isotope/Masonry, see: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your jsfiddle there is an extra div closing tag after the light green division.  Perhaps it should close the .foo division.

Second, to make the divs stack as depicted in your screenshot, you can float the second div to the right by adding the following rule set:

```
.foo div:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: what a cool rule i didnt know!! thanks, and it seems supported on all browsers except for the IE <= 8, and it works of course http://jsfiddle.net/w3htK/8/

Comment: For IE 8 and lower you need to use a shim.  http://html5polyfill.com/ is a pretty good database that lists different polyfills including selectivizr that implements CSS3 selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing your CSS with:

```
div.foo {
    float:left;
    max-width:50%;
    min-width:30%;
}
```

Comment: hey , actually a really good solution let me test something out with your example, i think i'll accept your answer if all works :P thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the divs to touch each other vertically?

You can use CSS Columns for that  http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns